# Xmppframework could not build module libxml

Tags: ios, libxml2, xmppframework

[image: Xcode]

On DDXMLNode.h

My project import XMPPFramework by cocoapods ,like:

`pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.6.6'`

I find some way like:

1.`header search paths` add "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2"

2.`Other Linker Flags` add "-lxml2"

3.`Framework Search Path` add "/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib"

All not working!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of changing path of the files, you can do what I have done to resolve my error in Xcode 7.2 beta. First check if you have file libxml2.tbd framework and libresolve.tbd framework; if not then add it to you project and replace few things:

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
//@import dnssd;
#import <dns_sd.h>
#else
//@import dnssdSimu;
#import <dns_sd.h>
#endif
```

Second thing you have to do is replace this one:

```
   #if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
   //@import libxml;
  #import <libxml/tree.h>
 #else
 //@import libxmlSimu;
 #import <libxml/tree.h>
  #endif
```

This resolved my problem.

Comment: I am facing similar error while working on xmpp-framework `/Users/..../Documents/PROJECTS/......./......./Libraries/XMPP Framework/Core/XMPPStream.h:5:9: 'CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h' file not found`

Comment: First of all check if the file exist in the project file if it exist then your project is not getting proper link. its better to go with podfile for the xmppFramework dependency so create prodfile with XMPPFramework dependency.

Comment: I didnt find the line to add in podfile for xmppframework inclusion into my project. Can me show me what i need to add into podfile?

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'XMPPFramework'           // Create Pod file and add these line in your pod file and then install pod file in your poject

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll say get down to business. I use Cocoapods at the beginning, everything goes well and do not configure something, but because of the need to modify the source code to meet certain requirements, so manually add XMPPFramework, but encountered all sorts of issues.

---

*The First* : **`Modlue 'libxmlSimu' not found`**

In order to solve this problem, I did two things:

1. Download the file https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML/blob/master/libxml/module.modulemap
   and import to your project. Like this: 
   [image]
2. Configure **Build Settings**  -  **Header Search Paths**, like this:
   [image]

---

*The Second* : **`Module 'KissXml' not found`**

By replace `@import KissXml;` to `#import "DDXML.h"`