# Export a Framework modulemap and use it for compilation (with XMPPFramework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmppframework, ios-frameworks

I am trying to create a Cocoa Framework from [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) (which, despite its name is not a Framework, but just a bunch of files).

I am doing this because the XMPPFramework project contains a lot of moving parts (copied source files from other projects, optional source files, weird includes) and we are trying to abstract this away from our main project and include it using Carthage like any other framework.

It almost works. I could include all the files, bundle it into a Framework in Xcode and build it with Carthage. There remains one only problem. Some public `.h` files contain funny includes like:

```c
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
@import libxml;
#else
@import libxmlSimu;
#endif
```

With a custom modulemap:

```
module libxml [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}

module libxmlSimu [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}

module dnssd [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/dns_sd.h"
    export *
}

module dnssdSimu [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/dns_sd.h"
    export *
}
```

You can find the related commit [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/commit/5aafcdfd27b6b4403e6e357f5687fabded3362ec).

I added the path of the modulemap file in the *Headers search path* build settings of Xcode. Compilation of the framework works fine.

However, when I include this header in my main project, those custom modules are not found and compilation fails. This is because those custom modules are not exported and the main project does not see them.

[image: Module 'libxmlSimu' not found]

I tried to create a custom modulemap file instead of having Xcode generating a generic one.

```
framework module XMPPFramework {
    umbrella header "XMPPFramework.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}

module libxml [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}

module libxmlSimu [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}

module dnssd [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/dns_sd.h"
    export *
}

module dnssdSimu [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/dns_sd.h"
    export *
}
```

And adding it to the Xcode config:

[image]

That's where I get into problems! It now seems that the custom modules are defined twice! Once by the XMPPFramework's modulemap file, and once by me.

[image]

*Fine!* I said. I'm just going to remove the modulemap path from the *Header search path* and it will solve it. Well, it does not... Now the custom modules cannot be found anymore:

[image]

To summarize:

- I need to define the custom modules in my modulemap otherwise the main project does not see them and is unable to compile.
- If I include the XMPPFramework's modulemap path in *Header search path*, I get a "duplicate module" error and it does not compile.
- If I include my own modulemap path in  *Header search path*, I also get the "duplicate module" error.
- If I do not include a modulemap path in *Header search path*, the compiler does not see the modules and it does not compile.

**How can I declare custom modules in my modulemap so that they are exported, and also use them while compiling the project?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595234/xmppframework-could-not-build-module-libxml/38215670#38215670 Have a try

Comment: hey do u find any sucess, even i am finding same issue

Comment: Sorry, no such luck :/